# Splice bug in safari, which versions affects ? (splice 0,0,x)

Tags: javascript, safari, splice

I found a strange bug in safari 7.0 on Mac, involving

- splice - add at begining
- sparse arrays

  `var x = [];x[1]=1;x[2]=2;console.log(x);`

  `x.splice(0,0,3);console.log(x);`

After last operation on all browsers the array is `[3,undefined,1,2]`
In safari is : `[3,undefined,1,1]`

I couldn't find more info about this problem, only that it resembles with some IE bugs. The question is anyone knows the official support ticket about it or on what Safari versions exists.

Comment: The Apple bug tracker is private. Apple uses duplicate count to prioritize bug fixes, so go ahead and file one if you feel confident that it's a bug. That said, I'd double-check if I was you, because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: As a reminder, Javascript does not have sparse arrays. When you insert past the bounds of an array, it's automatically extended with `undefined` values up to that index. There is no difference (or at least, there should be no difference) between `[undefined, 1, 2]` and the "sparse array" that you built in 3 steps.